# excel vba combobox

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

I want to populate a combobox with contents from a row (not a column) of values from another sheet, using VBA. If I assign the List to the row's range I only see the 1st value, so I guess excel insists on having a column of ranges. So, I was trying something like adding items:

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_GotFocus()

 Dim i As Integer
 Dim myArray As Variant

 myArray = Worksheets("data").Range("A4:PB4").Value

 For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
  Me.ComboBox2.AddItem myArray(i)
 Next

End Sub
```

Two problems. I don't think that's an array, it's a range. And, if I use add, I need to clear it everytime, but somehow using ComboBox2.Clear in the same routine clears it even after it's loaded? So nothing shows up :(

Got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to do the trick:

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_GotFocus()

  myArray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Worksheets("data").Range("A4:PB4"))
  With Me.ComboBox2
   .List = myArray
  End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The only mistake you made was not transposing and change myArray to type 'Range'

```
    myArray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Worksheets("data").Range("A4:PB4"))
     For each cell in myArray
     Me.combobox2.additem(cell)
    Next
```

Comment: I needed to add the clear command (ComboBox2.Clear) which caused the list to collapse to 1 line, but in this case it did clear the list. The 1st time it got focus it was OK. It's just on subsequent focus events that the list collapses (with Clear)....

Comment: Maybe it shouldn't be in the focus event?

Comment: So, you want to clear the combobox every time and then repopulate it when it gains focus again?

Comment: If you are wanting to clear the combobox everytime after the focus has left it, then put the combobox.clear segment in the 'Leave' event.  And in the focus event, place the code posted above.

Comment: I seem to have broke it by doing: myArray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Worksheets("data").Range("A4").End(xlToRight)) Is that not an array anymore?

Comment: After re-reading it, I think you can just do... Me.ComboBox2.AddRange(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Worksheets("data").range(Cells(4,1), cells(me.range("A4").end(xltoright)).value)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to avoid the array declaration here and just use the native format (range) of the thing you're using. Also calling the `clear` method before populating the combobox seems to work fine for me. It clears then repopulates. ?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim myRange As Range
 ComboBox1.Clear
 Set myRange = Worksheets("data").Range("A4:PB4")
 Dim c As Range
 For Each c In myRange 
  Me.ComboBox1.AddItem c.Value
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The clear command causes the list to collapse to 1 line so you cannot see it. Without the clear, it keeps growing larger (I can scroll through the items with the arrow key to prove what's populated there).

Comment: It does collapse on the first click...(it looks proper if you click again but still..) There must be a way around that.

Comment: I think it's that event. Is there anything special about you wanting to so this in the `Got_focus` event? Would you be fine using `Sub Worksheet_Activate()` or `Sub Workbook_Open()`? How often do you expect the values to change?

Comment: Just when the sheet is activated would be fine...but then I think Me. doesn't work, right?

Comment: It worked when I tried it. The code is still in the Sheet's class file. calling `Me` should reference that sheet. If you don't like it you can take it away.

Comment: How do I cause it to be attached only to a particular sheet?

Comment: Look in your project explorer. Code in the code file `Microsoft Excel Objects` > `Sheet1 (Sheet1)` is attached to that sheet. All references of `Me` within that code file refer to that sheet.

Comment: OK, thanks. The focus event seems to be more reliable than sheet events, or even a Click event on the combo. I don't know why, but it's not slowing the code down. Thanks a lot!

Comment: what's unreliable about the `activate` event?

Comment: If I open the book and it's already on that sheet, the event doesn't seem to occur.

Comment: I seem to have broke it by doing: myArray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Worksheets("data").Range("A4").End(xlToRight)) Is that not an array anymore?

Answer (score 0):

A better solution:

```
 Private Sub ComboBox1_GotFocus()

  Dim myArray As Variant

  lastcol = Worksheets("data").Range("A4").End(xlToRight).Column
  With Worksheets("data")
   Set SourceRng = .Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(4, lastcol))
  End With
  myArray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(SourceRng)
  With Me.ComboBox1
   .List = myArray
  End With

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

hier is the solution:

```
Sub PopulateComboBox()
    Dim n As Integer, i, names() As String
    n = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows("1:1"))
    ReDim names(n) As String
    For i = 1 To n
        names(i) = Cells(1, i)
        NameForm.ComboBox1.AddItem names(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```